# Javascript dynamic forms: How to create a dynamic form based on a dictionary object?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm new to javascript and it's my first Javascript project, I have some experience in writing simple codes, In my recent project, I have to build a dynamic form based on a dictionary object received from python backend. [image: dynamic form]

I want to create forms something like this in which there are some conditional parameters if you are selecting these conditional options it should populate nested input parameters based on drop-down selection.

bellow is the example of a dictionary object

```
[{'model_class': 'DataToolParameter',
  'name': 'infile',
  'argument': '--InFile1',
  'type': 'data',
  'label': 'Peptide data',
  'help': 'Input tabular file',
  'refresh_on_change': True,
  'optional': False,
  'hidden': False,
  'is_dynamic': False,
  'value': None,
  'extensions': ['tabular'],
  'edam': {'edam_formats': ['format_3475'], 'edam_data': ['data_0006']},
  'multiple': False,
  'options': {'hda': [], 'hdca': []}},
 {'model_class': 'TextToolParameter',
  'name': 'peps',
  'argument': '--PeptideColumn',
  'type': 'text',
  'label': 'Peptide Column',
  'help': 'Peptide Column Name',
  'refresh_on_change': False,
  'optional': False,
  'hidden': False,
  'is_dynamic': False,
  'value': '',
  'area': False,
  'datalist': []},
 {'model_class': 'Conditional',
  'name': 'selmethod',
  'type': 'conditional',
  'cases': [{'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
    'value': 'withlabel',
    'inputs': [{'model_class': 'TextToolParameter',
      'name': 'classlabel',
      'argument': '--SlcClassLabel',
      'type': 'text',
      'label': 'Column with the class label',
      'help': 'Select Class Label',
      'refresh_on_change': False,
      'optional': False,
      'hidden': False,
      'is_dynamic': False,
      'value': 'Class_label',
      'area': False,
      'datalist': []},
     {'model_class': 'Conditional',
      'name': 'advancefeature',
      'type': 'conditional',
      'cases': [{'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
        'value': 'advancefeature',
        'inputs': [{'model_class': 'TextToolParameter',
          'name': 'clmname',
          'argument': '--ClmPepID',
          'type': 'text',
          'label': 'Column name with peptide IDs',
          'help': 'Select Peptide ID Column',
          'refresh_on_change': False,
          'optional': False,
          'hidden': False,
          'is_dynamic': False,
          'value': '',
          'area': False,
          'datalist': []}]},
       {'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
        'value': 'normalfeature',
        'inputs': []}],
      'test_param': {'model_class': 'SelectToolParameter',
       'name': 'columnselect',
       'argument': '--Method',
       'type': 'select',
       'label': 'Peptide ID Column',
       'help': 'Split file if class labels are present',
       'refresh_on_change': True,
       'optional': False,
       'hidden': False,
       'is_dynamic': False,
       'value': 'normalfeature',
       'options': [[' Add Peptide ID Column Name ', 'advancefeature', False],
        [' No Peptide ID Column ', 'normalfeature', True]],
       'display': None,
       'multiple': False,
       'textable': False}}]},
   {'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
    'value': 'withoutlabel',
    'inputs': [{'model_class': 'Conditional',
      'name': 'advancefeature',
      'type': 'conditional',
      'cases': [{'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
        'value': 'advancefeature',
        'inputs': [{'model_class': 'TextToolParameter',
          'name': 'clmname',
          'argument': '--ClmPepID',
          'type': 'text',
          'label': 'Select Peptide ID Column',
          'help': 'Select Peptide ID Column',
          'refresh_on_change': False,
          'optional': False,
          'hidden': False,
          'is_dynamic': False,
          'value': '',
          'area': False,
          'datalist': []}]},
       {'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen',
        'value': 'normalfeature',
        'inputs': []}],
      'test_param': {'model_class': 'SelectToolParameter',
       'name': 'columnselect',
       'argument': '--Method',
       'type': 'select',
       'label': 'Column name with peptide IDs',
       'help': 'Split file if class labels are present',
       'refresh_on_change': True,
       'optional': False,
       'hidden': False,
       'is_dynamic': False,
       'value': 'normalfeature',
       'options': [[' Add Peptide ID Column Name ', 'advancefeature', False],
        [' No Peptide ID Column ', 'normalfeature', True]],
       'display': None,
       'multiple': False,
       'textable': False}}]}],
  'test_param': {'model_class': 'SelectToolParameter',
   'name': 'method',
   'argument': '--Method',
   'type': 'select',
   'label': 'Method to convert data',
   'help': 'Split file if class labels are present',
   'refresh_on_change': True,
   'optional': False,
   'hidden': False,
   'is_dynamic': False,
   'value': 'withlabel',
   'options': [[' Convert Without Split ', 'withoutlabel', False],
    ['Split Data By Class Label', 'withlabel', True]],
   'display': None,
   'multiple': False,
   'textable': False}}]
```

Based on conditional when `'cases': [{'model_class': 'ConditionalWhen'`
it should create this conditional section of the form. I am not able to write down a code that can solve my problem.

My biggest confusion here is that how to update a form and inputs  when a particular condition is being selected.

I have created various input blocks something like this.

```
addInputFiled (){


const InputSection = document.createElement('section')
InputSection.className = `input-section`
this.element.querySelector('.GalaxyForm').appendChild(InputSection)
const node = document.createElement("input");
node.className = 'Input'
this.element.querySelector('.input-section').appendChild(node)}

UpLoadData (){  
const UploadFile = document.createElement('section')
UploadFile.className = `uploadfile-section`
this.element.querySelector('.GalaxyForm').appendChild(UploadFile)
const FileUpload = document.createElement('input')  
FileUpload.type = 'file' 
FileUpload.id = 'uploadInput'    
FileUpload.style.color = 'transparent' 
FileUpload.text = 'FileUpload'       
this.element.querySelector('.uploadfile-section').appendChild(FileUpload) }
```

and based on the type of input block for example `input` or `file upload` I am updating the form element.

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            switch (inputs[i].type) {
                
            case "data":
                this.addInputFiled();
                break;
            case "integer" || "float":
                this.addInput(input_def);
                 break;
            case "boolean":
                 this.BooleanLabel(input_def);
                 break;
            case "select":
                this.addDropdown();
                break;
        }

    }
```

I am not able to figure out how to update a form and inputs  when a particular condition is being selected.

I tried several things but it didn't work for me, please help.

**Updated**

dictionary object has more than one inputs and its details `{'model_class': 'Conditional'` describes if dictionary object has any conditional block.

if a `model_class` is conditional it should have `cases` as you can see in the example object and for every `case` it has a `value` and (`ConditionalWhen`) when this `value`  selected from a drop down it should populates the `inputs` which exist in that `case` for example when  'value': 'withoutlabel' selected form should populate all the nested inputs  that belong to this `case`.

Comment: My suggestion, start from simple. You can extract one object from the data. Try to build one object only. Then, if you face a problem, you can focus on that problem and ask in SO later. I think building an input field should be an easy job for you.

Comment: @ikhvjs thank for you suggestion. I created various input elements block and based on type of input, using `switch` it append the child into the `form` element.  My biggest confusion here is how to update form when a particular option selected.

Comment: you need to describe what is the expected result of the ```model_class``` and and which ```model_classs``` are you struggling with? It would better show us the expected output in HTML instead of pictures.

Comment: @ikhvjs here is the example of a working form you can see an example on this like as an HTML. https://usegalaxy.org/root?tool_id=toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu%2Frepos%2Fiuc%2Ffeaturecounts%2Ffeaturecounts%2F2.0.1

Comment: You can focus the question on the ```model_class``` you are struggling with and show us the expected output instead of showing everything. For example, you just take out the one part of the ```model_class``` and tell use the expected output in HTML. It helps people to focus on your question more easily.